# Centova Cast Widget Customisation

Tags: java, html

so here are two pieces of Java, (sorry if i am wrong)

AutoDJ status: span id="cc_strinfo_autodj_300fsshoutcast" class="cc_streaminfo"
 (detects if auto dj is on with stream)

Source connected: span id="cc_strinfo_source_300fsshoutcast" class="cc_streaminfo">

these are for Centova Cast Shoutcast.

They show information on if the stream is active, Whether the AutoDJ Radio is on, and when a source is connected.

My question is can i customise this one

Source connected: span id="cc_strinfo_source_300fsshoutcast" class="cc_streaminfo">

to listen to the Auto DJ, detect if the answer is yes (states connected) and have the source default on NO.

And if the AutoDJ states Not connected, for the code to see if the Source has an active connection so to put into perspective

default

AutoDJ: Connected

Source: YES

**what i want.**

AutoDJ: Connected

Source: No

AutoDJ: Not connected

(script detects if source is connected eg live DJ)

Source: YES

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you